# Perpendicular line in the middle of two points Python

Tags: python, math, geometry

so I know this is basic high school math and I am rightfully ashamed, but my brain can't get around this.

I have two points `P1=(x1,y1)` and `P2=(x2,y2)` and need to draw the line that runs down the middle of [P1 P2] and is perpendicular to it.

I have the individual formulas: `midX=(x1+x2)/2`, `midY=(y1+y2)/2`, `slope=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)` and I know the resulting formula should look like `y=ax+b`

All pointers as to how to use which equation to get the result I need are gratefully received!

Comment: This is more of a math question than a programming question. I don't think this is on topic here.

Comment: @Aran-Fey my bad... Is there a math-overflow?

Comment: Yes, but [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) isn't the place you're looking for. Try [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/). (Do make sure your question is on topic there though. I can't guarantee that, because I'm not active there.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perpendicular vector has components

```
Perp = (-y2+y1, x2-x1)
```

And your line might be constructed using two points

```
(midX, midY) and (midX-y2+y1, midY + x2-x1)
```

Now you can define line equation in [desired form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Forms_for_two-dimensional_linear_equations) (note that `y=ax+b` is not universal approach)

Comment: which components? Please, be more precise.

Comment: Vector components. What is unclear?